# IF ELSE condition in SQL TO INSERT records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying for a time now to create a query that check if a records exists in a table then do nothing else insert record.I have seen multiple example for this task. From these example I have create a query.

**Query:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Answer () 
IF EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM answer WHERE a = 'a' && b = 'b' && e = 'e ' && timestamp = '1423828119' )
THEN 
BEGIN
SELECT 'This record already exists!' 
END 
IF ELSE 
BEGIN 
SELECT 'Record Added' 
INSERT INTO answer(a, b, c, d, e, timestamp) 
VALUES ('a','b','c','d','e','1423828119') 
END
```

**Error :**
`syntax to use near ' 'IF ELSE BEGIN SELECT 'Record Added' INSERT INTO answer(a, b,'`

not i am have a error on if condition in mysql.
Please just guide me toward right direction.

Comment: what exactly is an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` to check if a query returns anything:

```
if exists(
  select * 
  from answer 
  where a = 'a' and b = 'b' and e = 'e' and timestamp = '1423828119' 
) then begin
  select 'This record already exists!' 
end else begin
  select 'Record Added'
  insert into answer(a, b, c, d, e, $timestamp) 
  values ('a','b','c','d','e ','1423828119') 
end
```

Comment: `syntax to use near 'if exists( select * from answer where a = 'a' and 'b' at line 1`

Comment: @Xitas: Are you using the code in a stored procedure?

Comment: No! So I have to use store procedure to run this query?

Comment: @Xitas: Yes, the `if` statement is only used in stored procedures and functions.

Comment: I have update my question can you please look at my query last time.

Comment: @Xitas: You are missing a `begin` and `end` around the code. That's needed as there are more than one statement in the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

In most DBMSes there's a `MERGE` statement, but MySQL doesn't support it.

Following query doesn't need a Stored Procedure:

```
INSERT INTO answer(a, b, c, d, e, timestamp) 
SELECT 'a','b','c','d','e','1423828119'
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 ( 
   SELECT * FROM answer 
   WHERE a = 'a' AND b = 'b' AND e = 'e' AND timestamp = '1423828119
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `WHERE a = 'a' && b = 'b' && e = 'e' && timestamp = '1423828119'` you should use `WHERE a = 'a' AND b = 'b' AND e = 'e' AND timestamp = '1423828119'` (see instead of && i used AND)

Also you could use `IF EXIST` rather than `if TRUE` something like:

```
IF EXISTS (select ...) THEN
    select ...;
ELSE 
    ...
END IF;
```